# mongodump and mongorestore on PythonAnywhere

Tags: linux, mongodb, web2py, pythonanywhere, mongodump

I am using PythonAnywhere to host my web application. Using Mongodb as my database. Now my task is to take backup periodically and restore specific version of mongodb whenever I want.

To do it on local(windows machine), it is pretty easy. Install Mongodb utilities and execute command

```
mongodump --mongodbConnectionString   //From location where this executable is stored
mongorestore --mongodbConnectionString
```

Now my challenge is to do it from PythonAnywhere. Here how should I use these utilities?

---

I have Linux executables for mongodb from [mongodb site](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.4.0.tgz), I extracted bin folder from it, it look like below

[image]

Now I moved this bin folder to PythonAnywhere and tried to execute `mongodump` command

```
~/../applications/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.4.0/bin$ ./mongodump mongodbConnectionString
```

it failed with below error

> bash: ./mongodump: Permission denied

My question is how to do mongodump and mongorestore from PythonAnywhere? My final goal is to do periodic backup of mongodb database

Comment: Try: `sudo chmod u+x mongodump`

Comment: Hey @Valijon, thanks for your reply but in pythonanywhere environment we can not use `sudo` command https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/13178/

Comment: I mean: `Now I moved this bin folder to PythonAnywhere` you did it with shell ? If yes, you need to setup correctly persmission, owner, group, etc...

Comment: Yes, I set proper permissions and now I am able to do the dump mongodb database

Comment: @Valijon, thanks for your comment, it helped me to solve my problem, write an answer I will accept it. I am also writing answer on my own question which will give all steps regarding mongodb backup and restore

Comment: I've added an answer. Sure, add your steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup correctly MongoDB binaries inside PythonAnywhere.

Normally, execution fails due wrong permissions.

```
Make sure:
- You have execution permissions (chmod u+x file)
- Binnaries have proper owner    (chown user file)
- Binnaries have proper group    (chgrp group file)
```

**Note:** You need to be `sudoer` to grant such permissions

Answer (score 2):

As there is less documentation about mongodb backup and restore on PythonAnywhere environment, so writing here all steps to do backup and restore of mongodb on PythonAnywhere.

---

**Prerequisite:** You need Pythonanywhere account and Mongodb connection string.

---

**Steps to backup and restore mongodb on PythonAnywhere:**

1. Download `mongodump` and `mongorestore` executables for Linux machine from mongodb site
     https://www.mongodb.org/dl/linux/x86_64-ubuntu1404

   I downloaded *mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-4.0.16*, because I am using MongoDB 4.0
2. Extract it and upload required files(like `mongodump` and `mongorestore`) to PythonAnywhere's specific directory location.
3. After uploading these files, update its permission. I am windows user, so updated permission using `WinSCP -> right click to file -> properties -> Select Groups/Owner permission.`
4. Open Bash console from PythonAnywhere, go to directory where you stored `mongodump` and execute below command

   `~directory of your bin folder$ ./mongodump mongodb_connection_string.`

---

I was getting *bash: ./mongodump: Permission denied*, because I was not giving proper permissions to these files.

Comment: Looks like you've worked it out!  One thing to help anyone else struggling with the same problem -- you do *not* need to use `sudo` to change the permissions on a file.  Just `chmod +x filename` is enough, so long as you own the file -- which, if you uploaded it, you do.  (That's actually what WinSCP was doing behind the scenes.)